# How to save the return value from the query in Sails.js Console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql, node-repl

I am trying to run a simple query in my local Postgres db to return the User with an ID of 1 and save that value in the variable `record`. I'm using Sails.js and am in the Sails Console when I'm running these commands. I can get the query to print the object by running

`var record = User.find(1).exec(console.log);`,

but I can't seem to figure out how to save that value in a variable.

I've tried quite a few other things. `await` doesn't work in the Sails Console and all their documentation seems to use that.

I've also tried:

```
var record = User.find(1).exec(function(err, u){
    return u[0];
});

var record = User.find(1).exec(function(err, u){
    return u;
});
```

If I run:

```
var record = User.find(1).exec(function(err, u){
    console.log(Object.keys(u[0]));
});
```

it does print out all the keys to the user I'm querying, so I'm able to access the object, just can't figure out a way to save that object in a variable inside the Sails Console.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your Q. Are you trying to change the value of an attribute in Sails console? If so it should look like this: `User.updateOne(1).set({ firstName: Peter}).log()`

Comment: Honestly I'm just trying to query the database and save the returned records in a variable. It seems like something I should be able to accomplish. In the rails console, I would just do `record = User.find(1)` and then I could use record as a user object.

Comment: First declare variable `let record;` and then `User.find(1).exec(function(err, u){
    record = u; });` 
This also works `User.find(1).then(function(u){
    record = u; });`